# Unable to install Krita offline (snap), Ubuntu Budgie 20.10

Tags: snap, 20.10, krita, ubuntu-budgie

I've taken a copy of Krita and KDE framework as backup before I replaced Ubuntu with Ubuntu Budgie.

I don't have unlimited data plan so it was my last resort, because of many updates I had to install over again to keep the system up-to-date. And that took already big chunk of my limited data plan.

When I run `sudo snap install --dangerous krita_62.snap`, in return I get:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "krita" snap if present (run hook "configure": /snap/krita/x1/snap/command-chain/hooks-configure-desktop: line 43: /snap/krita/x1/kf5/usr/bin/fc-cache: No such file or directory)
```

Does anyone knows how to fix without downloading Krita over again?